# Add a variable in a variable

Tags: php

I have this variable:

`$imgmodp_data_1['path']`

but i would like to replace the 1 by another variable `$var`.
How do I proceed ?

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{}` to wrap the [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$number = 1;
${"imgmodp_data_".$number}["path"] = "foo";
$number = 2;
${"imgmodp_data_".$number}["path"] = "bar";

var_dump($imgmodp_data_1["path"]);
var_dump($imgmodp_data_2["path"]);
```